# robot framework list iteration - email address how to add recipient one by one

Tags: appium, robotframework

I want to enter recipient which I have stored them as variable.
I use FOR LOOP and first split the long list by separator ;
I wanted the email adderess being entered at TO-FIELD one by one like this:

```
aa@test.com;
bb@test.com;
cc@test.com;
```

At app, I expecting to see each of email accepted (shown as rounded accepted person at UI) after each separator ; is input.

**Variable (email list)**

```
Parameter
${RECIPIENTS}         aa@test.com;bb@test.com;cc@test.com;
```

**test case**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource     ../Resources/parameter.robot    

*** Test Cases ***
 Wait Until Page Contains And Click    ${TO-FIELD}    
    @{list}   Evaluate    "${RECIPIENTS}".split(';')
    FOR     ${EMAIL}    IN      @{list}
        Input Text   ${TO-FIELD}   ${EMAIL};
        Sleep    5s
    END
```

I got the weird behavior like this, which i am not sure which part went wrong.

**#1: `aa@test.com;` was entered** the recipient is not accepted by app

**#2: #1 is erased, then `aa@test.com;bb@test.com;cc@test.com;` was entered** the recipient is not accepted by app

Comment: And you are sure that it is not a bug in the tested app?

Comment: the erased behavior might be from input text command, i have tried adding press code 123 to for to end of line, still no luck.  so there is no issue at test case , loop or list all written well?